# Fullscreen video in JavaFx using HTML5 video tag

Tags: java, html, javafx, video, javafx-webengine

I am creating an application wherein I need to play a video within it. I am using the HTML5 `<video>`.

The video plays fine however I am not able to get the fullscreen option in the control bar of the video. I get the play/pause button, the seeking bar, but not the full screen button and the download button which are available in the `<video>` tag by default. Although the download button is not of any need to me, I need the full screen button.

Here is my code:

**App.java**:

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class App extends Application  {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("JavaFX Browser Loaded [OK]");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("file:///"+System.getProperty("user.dir")
                + File.separatorChar+"folder"
                +File.separatorChar+"index.html");

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState,       newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            }
        });

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((obs, oldState,       newState) -> {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        path = path.replace("\\", "/");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:///"+path + "\\logo.jpg"));

        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

//        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(0));
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            System.out.println("System Is Closing");
            System.exit(0);
        });
    }
}
```

**Index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

</body> 
</html>
```

**Here is an image of the player that I get:**

[image]

As you can see there is no full screen button.
Kindly help me out. Dont know where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, `WebView` does not support full screen at all. There's a [feature request (JDK-8091575)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091575) and a [mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2016-January/018511.html) regarding this topic.

Comment: @Slaw ok i’ll look into it. Thanks a lot.